# Symmetric spaces which are compact modulo the unipotent radical are compact

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups, symmetric-spaces

Is the following true?

Let $X = G/H$ be a symmetric space of a reductive group over a  p-adic field $F$. 
Let $X^0$ be an open orbit w.r.t. the action of the minimal parabolic $B$ of $G$. 
Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of $B$.

Assume that the quotient $U(F)\backslash X^0(F)$ is compact. Then $X(F)$ is compact.

If yes, we need a reference/proof of this fact.

Thank you very much